# Dynamically set person who queues a release to approver in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I have a two stage release:

1. Stage 1 creates a test DB
2. pre-deploy approval on Stage 2
3. Stage 2 test DB just created is destroyed

This setup allows devs time to test changes before approving automated cleanup.

My question is, is it possible to dynamically set the pre-deploy approval (step #2 above) to the user who submitted the release? If not, perhaps there is a better way to pause the release until the submitter manually allows it to continue?

Answer (score 1):

For this issue , you can try to set approver through the [Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples) rest api.

You can add approver in "preDeployApprovals" argument. For example:

```
"preDeployApprovals": {
                "approvals": [{
                    "approver": {
                        "id": "9f723013-a332-64e5-aea9-6e3ebxxxxx",
                        "displayName": "hughl01",
                        "isContainer": false
                    },
                    "isAutomated": false,
                    "isNotificationOn": false,
                    "rank": 1,
                    "id": 0
                }]
            },
```

Then you can set the pre-deploy approval to the user who submitted the release through pre-defined variables:

- `Release.RequestedFor`   The display name of identity that triggered
  the release.
- `Release.RequestedForId`   The ID of identity that triggered the
  release.

In the request body ,you can use `$(Release.RequestedFor)` to dynamically get the name of the user who triggered the release and use it as the name of approver. The same goes for  `$(Release.RequestedForId)`.

Here are some references for you:

[set approver with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48447956/tfs-set-approver-with-powershell)

[release pre-defined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#release-variables)